# Filesystem TtreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, treeview

I found an example of showing the filesystem tree (like in Windows Explorer) on MSDN [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/File-system-TreeView-72549a6f). Do you know any alternative for this in WinForms? Thanks in advance!

The example linked above, reports the following error when running:
[image]

Is anybody meeting the same error?

Comment: how are you running your application?  are you clicking debug in VS?

Comment: by pressing F5 (sure, in Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: in my case its working perfectly @VictorBarbu and why have your added the **winforms** tag, its **WPF**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, WinForms has it's own bulit-in [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) control that you can use.  From there you can populate it manually. using the [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) namespace

Comment: But, about that example, could you explain me why doesn't work, because I haven't enough knowledge to find out... I would be truely grateful!

Comment: i will put here a print screen